# Bottleneck does not seem to actually rate-limit requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rate-limiting, bottleneck

I am writing a program which needs to iterate through a number of items, performing an HTTP GET request on each item in turn. The HTTP GET request is rate-limited by the third-party API to a maximum of 5 requests per minute. I am trying to use Bottleneck to limit my requests out to this API, to little success.

A minimum example of my problem is as follows:

```
// index.ts
import * as API from "./lib/API";

(async () => {
  try {
    //Gather all requests
    const list_of_requests = await API.Requests.get_list_of_all_requests(...);

    // Fire off each request at the appropriate rate
    list_of_requests.forEach(async (request) => {
      try {
        const request_result = await API.ResultGetter.get_result(...);

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.name + ": " + error.message);
  }
})();
```

Within my `./lib/API`:

```
// API.ts
import { AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";
import { scheduleRequest } from "../util/Limiter";

export async function ResultGetter(...) {
     const requestURL: string = "https://www.website.ext/...";

  const requestConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    url: requestURL,
    method: "GET",
    responseType: "json",
  };

return await scheduleRequest(requestConfig);
}
```

And finally, in my `util/Limiter`

```
// Limiter.ts
import Bottleneck from "bottleneck";
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from "axios";

/*
5 API requests per minute; 500 API requests per day
*/
export const limiter = new Bottleneck({
  reservoir: 500, 
  reservoirRefreshAmount: 500,
  reservoirRefreshInterval: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  maxConcurrent: 1,
  mintime: Math.ceil(1 / (5 / 60 / 1000)),
});

export async function scheduleRequest(
  request: AxiosRequestConfig
): Promise<AxiosResponse<any>> {
  return limiter.schedule(() => axios(request));
}
```

However, when I actually utilize this program the requests fire off at the fastest rate possible. I'm truly not sure what I'm missing in this case. To my understanding, `limiter.schedule(...)` should be returning a promise that resolves when the request happens, limited by the rate limit set. But that is not what's happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was just a difficult to find typo.

In my original code, I had the following to define my rate limiter:

```
export const limiter = new Bottleneck({
  reservoir: 500, 
  reservoirRefreshAmount: 500,
  reservoirRefreshInterval: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  maxConcurrent: 1,
  mintime: Math.ceil(1 / (5 / 60 / 1000)),
});
```

Well the fact that I wrote `mintime` instead of `minTime` with a capital `T` made all the difference in the world.